# Spotfire Map Multiple Values in same geo code

Tags: geolocation, spotfire

Im drawing a simple map in spotfire using US cities as geo location. The values I want to show on the map is the location of 'specific gas stations' by the geo code.

For larger cities there are many but im only able to get one 'shape'. I can work on the coloring or size. But im interested to get all 5 dots next to each other or a call-out highlighting there are five..?

Is there a way to show all values, or does spotfire need to combine them?

I know I can get more details with lat/long but that is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are your shapes literally being combined? that shouldn't happen unless you are doing a "Marker by: City". double check this setting.

if they aren't being literally combined into one point on the map, but instead they are sitting on top of each other, you could adjust the jitter settings on your Marker Layer (check the Appearance page in the Properties dialog) to spread them out a little bit.

if that doesn't suit your needs, and the former case is true, please update your question with some screencaps of your map chart's configuration and I'll see if I can provide a better answer :)